# LINQ Query Issue DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

while doing LINQ I got this Error. 
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I know its because of the data type but Convert is not working is there any other way to do it.
here is my code.

```
        {var tvr = from t in ce.tbl_TVRinfo
                  where t.TVRID == fTVRid
                  select new TVRDetails
                  {
                      TVRID = t.TVRID,
                      Ename = t.Ename,
                      Esdw = t.Esdw,
                      Edob =t.Edob, //this field is causing date conversion error
                      Epob = t.Epob,
                      Equalification = t.Equalification,
                      NIC = t.NIC,
                      EAddress = t.EAddress
                  }
        return tvr.ToList();
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a Nullable DateTime to a standard DateTime.  If you are confident that the Nullable DateTime  contains a value then you could do:

```
Edob =t.Edob.Value
```

Or if you are not sure it has a value:

```
Edob = t.Edob.HasValue ? t.Edob.Value : SomeOtherValidDateTimeValue
```

Comment: Naveed, as I mentioned though, this will fail if t.Edob.Value is null.  So you may need to work around that, unless you are 100% confident that it will never be so, although this is very rarely the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
Edob = (DateTime)t.Edob
```

but an exception will be raised if t.Edob is null.
Better still would be to provide a default datetime if Edob is null. The NULL coalescing operator is useful here.

```
Edob = t.Edob ?? DateTime.Now // Or DateTime.MinValue, or whatever makes sense in your situation
```

Comment: It does work, but @Darren's answer is a bit more elegant. Note that as we've both said, you will get a rull time NullReferenceException if t.Edob is null unless you use the null coalescing version.